# Import statement automatically converted to multi-line in VSCODE

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, formatting, angular7, prettier

My VSCode editor automatically wraps import statements into new lines on save or format document:

Before:
[image]

After:

[image]

I don't want this behaviour. How to disable this rule?

I am programming in Angular 7 typescript and following extension is installed on it:

1. Angular Essentials
2. Prettier
3. TSlint

Please, help me to remove this rule or behavior.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is caused by Prettier.

I don't think you can disable this on its own (short of using a `// prettier-ignore` comment above the import) but you can try increasing the line length at which prettier starts wrapping with the `prettier.printWidth` setting

Comment: Thank you for `// prettier-ignore`, I didn't know that. But also, its a hack and can't use on top of every import. Can I disable `prettier.printWidth`?

Comment: Unfortunately, // prettier-ignore doesn't work in my case. Prettier, well, ignores that ignore statement. Still trying to find a way to prevent Prettier to make my code ugly.

Comment: If you are sharing a codebase then you might want to do this inside a `.prettierrc` file in the root of your project.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot disable prettier.printWidth, but you can increase the line-length until it so that it stops wrapping your imports.

You can do this by opening (or creating) a file called prettier.rc in the root dir (one above /src in an Angular project) and adding the property:

```
"printWidth": 250
```

or whatever number is required.

A word of warning: As the printWidth is a central theme of Prettier - as an opinionated formatter, what you are trying to do may not be the best option in the long-term.

For Angular project, as opposed to using Prettier consider adding new rules to tslint or even creating custom rules where required.

Comment: I tried to update the printWidth property from the extension settings in the VS code directly which did'nt work. 

It worked by adding printWidth property inside prettier.rc.js as suggested in the answer. Thanks.